# How to resize a bunch of images of different formats stored in different folders

Tags: images, recursive

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Bulk convert photos to smaller size?](https://superuser.com/questions/61206/bulk-convert-photos-to-smaller-size)

Hi Guys,

I need to resize a bunch of images that are stored in a detailed folder structure. I want the resizing to replace the original file, and I also want it to keep it in the same directory structure as it is in.

I am on windows 7, but also have access to an ubuntu install.

Can anyone recommend an application or way to do this?

Thanks

Jason

Answer (score 0):

This worked perfectly.
http://www.fotosizer.com/

It's a freeware that allows you to select a folder.
It will then scan that folder (and subfolders, optionally) for all image types, you know, tif, bmp, jpg, png etc.

It'll then allow you to resize them into a constraining box - ie set a max width and height and then resize them. It can overwrite original files, or even better it can recreate your folder structure in the folder of your choice.

Works well, good price (free!)

Comment: Please refrain from just posting a link, but rather give a quick summary of what it says.